# Animate span from 0px to ...%?

Tags: css, css-animations

Im trying to make a simple CSS Animation

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xT8z9/

I need it to stay at 100% width value, but due to animation it poofs back to 0%.

```
@-webkit-keyframes meter1 {
  0% {
    width:0%;
  }

  100% {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

How do I fix this, do I need javascript or jquery for this?

Greetings, Chris

Comment: Your fiddle's html is missing a closing tag, I am not seeing anything animate at all

Comment: with the closing tag : http://jsfiddle.net/xT8z9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`, to maintain the final state.

```
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    width:0px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color:#0f0;
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
            animation: meter1 1s 1s ease forwards;  
    -webkit-animation: meter1 1s 1s ease forwards;  
       -moz-animation: meter1 1s 1s ease forwards;  
         -o-animation: meter1 1s 1s ease forwards;  
        -ms-animation: meter1 1s 1s ease forwards;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xT8z9/2/)**

**[MDN animation-fill-mode documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)**